# Is the generalized directional derivative additive?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $f,g:X\to\mathbb R$ be locally Lipschitz continuous on a neighborhood of $x\in X$. The generalized directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in the direction $v\in X$ is defined as $$f^\circ(x;v):=\limsup_{\substack{y\to x\\t\to0+}}\frac{f(y+tv)-f(y)}t.$$

> Are we able to show that $(f+g)^\circ(x;v)=f^\circ(x;v)+g^\circ(x;v)$?

By the usual subadditivity of $\limsup$ we've got at least "$\le$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f = -g = x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which is Lipschitz.  Then, both $f^{\circ} (0, 1) = g^{\circ} (0, 1) = 1$, whereas $(f+g)^{\circ} (0, 1) = 0$

Comment: So, in general only "$\le$" and "$=$" only if $f$ and $g$ admit classical directional derivatives, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d i think you meant "if" and not "only if".

Comment: @CalvinKhor Actually, I've meant the "if" holds only in the mentioned case; quite weird logically.